# Grabbing regex variables for 0 or 1 match

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to refer to the 2 different regex variables that have the same name?

For instance:

```
log1: 12-3-04: type=type1 event=GET user=thomas access_level=4 ip=1.1.1.1 port=443 dstip=2.2.2.2 dstport=432

log2: 12-3-04: type=type1 event=GET user=brad userdb=Admin ip=1.1.1.1 access_level=2
```

These two events are the same `type` however their format is a bit different

regex:

the events common regex

```
\d+\-\d+\-\d+\:\s+type=(?P<type>\S+)\s+event\=(?P<event>\S+)\s+user\=(?P<user>\S+)\s+
```

log1 regex:

```
access_level\=(?P<access_level>\d+)\s+ip\=(?P<\S+>)\s+port\=(?P<\d+>)\s+dstip\=(?P<dstip>\S+)\s+dstport\=(?P<\d+>)
```

log2 regex:

```
userdb\=(?P<userdb>\S+)\s+ip\=(?P<ip>\S+)\s+access_level\=(?P<access_level>\d+)
```

Because these event types are the same, I want a 1 regex to capture both these events.
What I had in mind was

```
(common regex) + (log1 regex)? + (log2 regex)?
```

This captures both events BUT the variable names that are common must be named differently. For example `access_level`. I want to be able to refer to `access_level` and have the logic automatically know which `access_level` I want.

```
\d+\-\d+\-\d+\:\s+type=(?P<type>\S+)\s+event\=(?P<event>\S+)\s+user\=(?P<user>\S+)\s+(access_level\=(?P<access_level>\d+)\s+ip\=(?P<\S+>)\s+port\=(?P<\d+>)\s+dstip\=(?P<dstip>\S+)\s+dstport\=(?P<\d+>))?(userdb\=(?P<userdb>\S+)\s+ip\=(?P<ip>\S+)\s+access_level\=(?P<access_level>\d+))?
```

Comment: Is regex really needed for this? `dict(x.split('=') for x in line.split()[2:])` gives you something far easier to work with.

Comment: @roippi I am writing a plugin so I scan log files with really long lines of regex haha sucks but I have to do it

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. A small function will do the job and is easier to read.

```
def parse_log_line(line):
    name, date, *pairs = line.split(" ")
    name = name.rstrip(":")
    date = date.rstrip(":")
    data = dict(pair.split("=", 2) for pair in pairs)
    return (name, date, data)

a = "log1: 12-3-04: type=type1 event=GET user=thomas access_level=4 ip=1.1.1.1 port=443 dstip=2.2.2.2 dstport=432"
b = "log2: 12-3-04: type=type1 event=GET user=brad userdb=Admin ip=1.1.1.1 access_level=2"

print(parse_log_line(a)[2]["access_level"])
print(parse_log_line(b)[2]["access_level"])
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

(common regexp) + (part of log 2 before access_level)? + (access_level regexp) + (part of log 1 after access_level)?

E.g.:

```
\d+\-\d+\-\d+\:\s+type=(?P<type>\S+)\s+event\=(?P<event>\S+)\s+user\=(?P<user>\S+)\s+(userdb\=(?P<userdb>\S+)\s+ip\=(?P<ip>\S+)\s+)?access_level\=(?P<access_level>\d+)(\s+ip\=(?P<ip2>\S+)\s+port\=(?P<port>\d+)\s+dstip\=(?P<dstip>\S+)\s+dstport\=(?P<dstport>\d+))?
```

Please test carefully :-)

I see that this does only work for access_level and not for ip.

Comment: Thank you for help but for my case that wont really work